# how to count keys present in array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an below array. I wanted to know how many time `selectedOption` key is present in array of Object. In, some object we don't have key `selectedOption`. So, the count of key `selectedOption`  should return 4. How we can count these key in javascript ?

```
let data = [{
  id: 123,
  selectedOption: "ABC",
  value: 345
}, {
  id: 234,
  selectedOption: "BCD",
  value: 345
}, {
  id: 356,
  selectedOption: "BGY",
  value: 678
}, {
  id: 456,
  selectedOption: "BCD",
  value: 890
}, {
  id: 870: value: 980
}, {
  id: 385,
  value: 654
}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A simple loop with an `if (typeof ...)` should do the job.

Answer (score 6):

```
data.filter(datum => datum.selectedOption).length
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.filter(d => d.hasOwnProperty('selectedOption')).length`

This is a more full proof solution compared to `data.filter(datum => datum.selectedOption).length` because if `selectedOption` was a boolean flag with `false` value it wouldn't be counted.

`hasOwnProperty` will check if the property exists on the object irrespective of the value.

For example in this case

```
let data = [{
  id: 123,
  selectedOption: false,
  value: 345
}, {
  id: 234,
  selectedOption: false,
  value: 345
}, {
  id: 356,
  selectedOption: true,
  value: 678
}, {
  id: 456,
  selectedOption: false,
  value: 890
}, {
  id: 870,
  value: 980
}, {
  id: 385,
  value: 654
}];
```

1. `data.filter(d => d.hasOwnProperty('selectedOption')).length` Output: `4`
2. `data.filter(datum => datum.selectedOption).length` Output: `1`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for the suggestion, I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways it can be done. In the below function ,reduce is used. Inside reduce callback it is checking if the object has `selectedOption` key then increment 1

```js
let data = [{
  id: 123,
  selectedOption: "ABC",
  value: 345
}, {
  id: 234,
  selectedOption: "BCD",
  value: 345
}, {
  id: 356,
  selectedOption: "BGY",
  value: 678
}, {
  id: 456,
  selectedOption: "BCD",
  value: 890
}, {
  id: 870,
  value: 980
}, {
  id: 385,
  value: 654
}];

let countSelectedOption = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc += curr.selectedOption ? 1 : 0;
  return acc;
}, 0);
console.log(countSelectedOption)
```